# Spinner that is animating even when long running JavaScript is running

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to create a spinner that is animating even when long running JavaScript is executing? Currently I have a gif that is freezed when long running JavaScript is running. I have a report that I have to generate client side that is based on DOM operations, so I cannot move it to web worker nor to server.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: yeah, use font-awesome `fa-spinner`, or simply use css animation to rotate the image. For some reason it executes in a different way than the gif.

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icon/spinner/

Comment: <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i> works in Chrome, in IE11 unfortunatelly not.